pkcs12 file exported with no password doesn't gets imported in macOS Sequoia 15.0 (24A335)
I exported the pkcs12 file which contains the Apple Distribution Certificate with the Private Key on macOS Sonoma 14 with no password.
I was able to import the same on different macOS Sonoma 14 machines as follows:
security import \
  apple-distribution-hrk.p12 \
  -k /Users/hrk/Library/Keychains/non-default.keychain-db \
  -f pkcs12 \
  -P "" \
  -A

But when upgraded to macOS Sequoia 15.0 (24A335), running the above command gives me the following error:
security: SecKeychainItemImport: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.

Workaround
I didn't have the Private Key of the original macOS Sonoma 14 from which the pkcs12 file was exported.
So, I had to create the new Certificate by uploading the Certificate Signing Request, download the .cer file, import it, and then export the pkcs12 file with some password.
Then I was able to import the pkcs12 file with the password.
Question
I couldn't find any reference to this Breaking Change in the Release Notes of macOS Sequoia 15.0 (24A335).
Can somebody point to the official documentation that refers to this Breaking Change?
Or is this the bug in macOS Sequoia 15.0 (24A335)?
References

Apple Developer Forums Post: 764429
Filed the Feedback: FB15250516

Edits
This bug still exists in the following updates:

macOS Sequoia 15.0.1 (24A348)

